# Destructure a map in another map?

Tags: clojure, destructuring

I have the following data structure:

```
{:file #<File /foo.bar>, :resolution {:width 1280, :height 1024}}
```

I would like to write a function that destructures the `:resolution` key into `width` and `height` symbols.  Something like

```
(defn to-directory-name [{{:keys [width height]}} wallpaper]
  (str width "x" height))
```

Is something like that possible with destructuring?

Thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You must first destructure :resolution, then get width and height:

```
{{:keys [width height]} :resolution}
```

Comment: How can I destructure from within two different nested keys of the same map? e.g. `{{:keys [a b]} :query-params}` and `{{:keys [c d]} :path-params}` simultaneously, from the same request map

Comment: Just put them in the same `{}`: `{{:keys [a b]} :query-params {:keys [c d]} :path-params}`

Comment: in case `:resolution` contains a much larger data structure, is there a way to destructre `width` and `height` and *still* make resolution referencable? i.e. after destructre being able to still access resolution keys like so - `(keys resolution)`?

Comment: `{{:keys [width height]} :resolution  
 :as option-map`
or you can use within {:keys ....} if you only need ref to resolution.

Answer (score 6):

```
(defn to-directory-name [{{width :width height :height} :resolution}] 
  (str width "x" height))
```

Works for me.